# Is it possible to query out all of the "praises" messages from yammer?

Tags: yammer

Yammer has a feature that allows you to "praise" someone.  However, looking at the data that is returned from a "praise" message, it does not appear there is any distinguishing flag or attribute that marks it as a "praise" message.  Inside the message, there is an attachment with "type=praise" and then "praised-user-id".

What is the best way to pull this information out of Yammer?

[image: Yammer Message JSON]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to pull all praise messages from Yammer at this time. It's worth joining the [Yammer Developer Network](https://developer.yammer.com/) and tracking updates to the API, but this is not something that I'd expect to see in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking slightly on a tangent, try using the 'search' API looking for the word 'praised' as this is always in the body. This should return only results containing praised.